# Debian resolver adds domain and I don't want that

Tags: debian, resolv.conf, domain-name-system

I have the following problem:
if I ping a non existent domain name I get a reply from an IP address
`# ping nosuchdomain.common
PING nosuchdomain.common.myrealdomain.com (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from myrealdomain.com (192.168.1.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=59 time=0.184 ms`

Anyway, what I would want to happen would be to have the resolver work like this
`#ping nosuchdomain.common
ping: unknown host nosuchdomain.common`

My /etc/resolv.conf looks like this now:
`# nameserver config
nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Any idea where I should look to make the resolver return "unknown host"?

Comment: You have so obfuscated this question that it's hard to answer.  It implies that you have embedded `192.168` addresses in your public DNS; that's possible, but unlikely, which makes me wonder which of the above data can be relied on.  Please strongly consider de-obfuscating your question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't believe the real data was relevant, it is like this # ping sajnkjgabk.caomdas
PING sajnkjgabk.caomdas.geek-tools.org (144.76.100.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from siteintel.net (144.76.100.150): icmp_req=1 ttl=59 time=0.410 ms

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'm not a debian user, but are you by any chance running `nscd`?

Comment: no, it isn't started.

Comment: That disposes of that hypothesis.  Just on another offchance, could you **edit into your question** the outputs of `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` and `grep caomdas /etc/hosts`?

Comment: @MadHatter `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf 
hosts:          files dns`. The other one does not return anything

Answer (score 1):

Normaly you should end a Domain Name with a dot, if you don't do this your resolver try to attach a search Domain from you network config (for example from DHCP)

Your example with `nosuchdomain.common` should be written as `nosuchdomain.common.`

To find out the reason where is set the search domain, you can use a static IP and set a different DNS Server and than you should not get a search domain. You should check you /etc/network/interfaces config for a search-domain parameter:

```
#/etc/network/interfaces 
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    dns-search myrealdomain.com
```

Comment: well, I would like the resolver not to add the domain at the end. I knew that this was configurable from /etc/resolv.conf but there I have not such domain defined.

Comment: Right, kockiren, but (s)he's posted his/her name server config and there's no domain search order listed.

Comment: Okay can you do a ls -lah |grep resolv of your /etc folder? What client you have? Do you use DHCP or static IP? Do you use a DNS rewrite on you DNS Server?

Comment: It is possible to set multiple resolver conf so it can happened that you resolve.conf has not that config part but the other one use a search domain.

Comment: `ls -lah |grep resolv  
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4.0K Nov 27 13:58 resolvconf  
-rw-r--r--   1 root root        268 Mar 27 10:44 resolv.conf`

Comment: As far as I can tell I use a statically defined IP address (defined in /etc/network/interfaces) and there is no dhcp-related process running. I am not aware of a DNS rewrite (not sure what that is) but I am also not aware what this could have to do with my resolver issue?

Comment: @kockiren how can I check this multiple-resolver possibility?

Comment: I use a pfsense firewall and I can rewrite every DNS request who run over the Gateway. There I can add a Domain to every request. What Gateway you use? What DNS Server you use?

Comment: What are the contents of the files in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d` (**please, please, paste these into your question - don't add them as comments**)?

Comment: @MadHatterthere is no such file/directory inside `/etc/resolvconf`

Comment: @kockiren I see. I don't use a DNS on this server, I just connect to 8.8.8.8 to resolve the domain names. Also as firewall is a simple iptables so that's not an issue.

Comment: And what is the Content of /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: @kockiren please see my solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your suggestions, I accidentally found a solution to my problem and that is to explicitly add this line in /etc/resolv.conf
`search .com`
Once I did this it started working as expected.
I guess the resolver has a default `search` as the domain of what is defined in `/etc/hostname` to which it adds whatever domain it cannot resolve directly.
And as my DNS for this domain was configured with wildcard it explains why the made up domains were resolved to a certain IP.